# Non-Mock Android Integration tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

In iOS I can make an integration test like this

```
// Setup expecttation to prevent from test ending before all async tasks finish.
let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Sign in");

// call API method for signing in
PersonAPI.signIn("asdf@asdf.co", password: "Free Milk Lane", done:{(response: APIResponse)->Void in

    // check response for errors
    XCTAssertTrue(response.isSuccessful() == true, response.getMessage());

    // mark async operation is completed
    expectation.fulfill();
});

// wait until all async operations completed
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5.0, handler:nil);
```

But in Android its not so obvious. Right now I am trying to use Roboelectric & Retrofit but it just doesn't want to cooperate. I have tried lots of things and I think the issue is related to how the threads for are pooled. For example the following code will pass but waits 5 seconds no matter what, even though the API call may only take 1 second:

```
// Setup signal to prevent from test ending before all async tasks finish.
final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

// call API method for signing in
PersonAPI.signIn("asdf@asdf.co", "Free Milk Lane", new IAPICallback() {public void done(APIResponse response) {

    // check response for errors
    Assert.assertTrue(response.getMessage(), response.isSuccessful());

    // mark async operation is completed
    signal.countDown();
}});

// wait until all async operations completed
signal.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

At this point I'm willing to try anything (except mocking). Change out the retrofit, reoboelectric, whatever.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I made it work. I changed retrofit to do synchronous calls. Then I stored the response in a static variable and completed the assertions on the main thread.

```
public class PersonAPITest {
        private static APIResponse _response = null;

        @Test
        public void testSignIn() {
            // Setup signal to prevent from test ending before all async tasks finish.
            final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

            // call API method for signing in
            PersonAPI.signIn("asdf@asdf.co", "Free Milk Lane", new IAPICallback() {public void done(APIResponse response) {

               // check response for errors
               PersonAPITest._response = response;

               // mark async operation is completed
               signal.countDown();
            }});

          // wait until all async operations completed
          signal.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

          Assert.assertTrue(PersonAPITest._response.getMessage(), PersonAPITest._response.isSuccessful());
        }
    }
```

An example of the retrofit code is below. Basically I just used native Java multi-threading to create the asynchronous method:

```
public static void getGoogle(final IAPICallback callback) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                        .setEndpoint("http://google.com")
                        .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));
                RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();
                ITaskAPI service = (ITaskAPI) adapter.create(ITaskAPI.class);

                Response result = service.getGoogle();

                APIResponse response;

                if(result.getStatus() == 200) {
                    response = new APIResponse(true, "it worked!");
                }else{
                    response = new APIResponse(false, "boo! bad dog!");
                }

                callback.done(response);
            }
        }).start();
    }
```